# juju cant ssh service units

Tags: server, ssh, juju, maas, ceph

I have deployed Ceph with Juju. I am trying to ssh in with the following command:

```
sam@maas01:~$ sudo juju ssh ceph/0
Permission denied (publickey,password).
error: exit status 255
```

I have my public key in /home/sam/.ssh/. I had also tried to explicitly specify the key's path in enviornments.yaml file which didn't help.
And as I had seen in many posts not to add ssh keys in MAAS web panel, I haven't added they key there. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! i got it working :D. instead of sudoer user ssh key i added root user ssh key.

Answer (score 3):

I do think you need to add your key to MAAS, and, frustratingly, juju destroy-machine and redeploy.

> i had seen in many posts not to add ssh keys in MAAS web panel

Btw, where did you read that? If you remember it would be good to know, so that I can add a comment or something. If I'm right.

Comment: hi gavin, thats bad :( then i think, i have destroy the full environment and redeploy everything. I had read that not to add ssh key in maas preference page on some email thread for ssh issue , i'll check if i have in my history. But then do i need to redeploy juju zookeeper also again?

Comment: ok i have destroyed environment, and this time i have copied my public key in maas preference page, and also my juju zookeper is up, so just befor proceeding further i tried to ssh juju zookeper machine with cmd " sudo juju ssh 0" but it gave me same error,
Warning: Permanently added 'x4737.master,192.168.178.50' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
error: exit status 255